# SQL ROUND A AVG

Tags: sql

I have that 2 tables:

```
Evaluation
id_student  teste
----------- -----
1           16
1           10
1           20
1           13

Student
id          name
----------- ------
1           Jonh
```

And I want do the average of the column "teste" for the student with the id 1.
I used that query:

```
select ROUND(AVG(e.teste),0) from Student s, Evaluation e
where s.id=e.id_student and s.id=1 group by s.nome
```

That query return the value 14, but if i go to the calculator and do (16+10+20+13) / 4 it gives me 14.75 I already tryed with the ROUND to round the number, the query should return 15 instaed of 14.
Somebody know how I can soulve this? Thanks and sorry my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that the average is calculated using *integer* arithmetic.  You don't specify your database, but some do use integer arithmetic.  This has nothing to do with the `round()`.

Try this out:

```
select AVG(e.teste)
from Student s join
     Evaluation e
     on s.id = e.id_student 
where s.id = 1;
```

Notice the changes:

- Fixed the `join` use proper, explicit `join` syntax.
- Removed the `round()`.
- Removed the `group by` because you only seem to want to return one row.

This will return `14` and not `15`, because the calculation is integer 59 divided by integer 4 to return an integer -- so it is truncated not rounded.  You can fix this by converting to some sort of decimal/float representation.  Often the easiest way is just by multiplying by 1.0:

```
select AVG(e.teste * 1.0)
from Student s join
     Evaluation e
     on s.id = e.id_student 
where s.id = 1;
```

Once you have the average calculating correctly, you can apply `round()` if you like.

Comment: My column teste is a tinyint.

Comment: @youarebannedfromStackoverf `tinyint` still uses integer arithmetic

Comment: I tryied your query and return 14.7500000 then I tryied with ROUND(AVG(e.teste * 1.0), 0) and returned 15.0000000